# how to express logical or between two strings in regex of python?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
string="上市以来，向上市公司股东共募集资金 3.36 亿元"
fi1=re.search("募集资金(\s*\d*\.\d*\s*)亿元",string).group(1)
print(fi1)
fi2=re.search("募资共(\s*\d*\.\d*\s*)亿元" or "募集资金(\s*\d*\.\d*\s*)亿元",string).group(1)
print(fi2)
fi3=re.search(r"募资共(\s*\d*\.\d*\s*)亿元|募集资金(\s*\d*\.\d*\s*)亿元",string).group(1)
print(fi3)
```

`fi1` can get 3.36 from string,why  `fi2` and `fi3` can get nothing ?how to express a regex in python betwwen two strings in which there is a logical or relationship?

Comment: `fi3` is the right way to do it. But there you have 2 groups, and your value is in the 2nd group, not the first that you are getting.

Comment: `fi3=re.search(r"募资共(\s*\d*\.\d*\s*)亿元|募集资金(\s*\d*\.\d*\s*)亿元",str
ing).group(2)` make it done,but how can i know which () is searched? 1 or 2? can i make my code more smart?

Comment: Group 1 would be empty/undefined if it doesn't match. In code pick the first group which is set.

Comment: Just do what Qtax says if you have unalike expressions, just check both and see which one has a valid capture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reformulate your third approach

```
fi3=re.search(r"(?:募资共|募集资金)(\s*\d*\.\d*\s*)亿元",string).group(1)
```

`(?:募资共|募集资金)` is a [non capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), so that your result is always in `group(1)`.

Comment: if there is a compilcated expression ,i have to choose group 1 or two ,how can i make my code smart?  re.search("xx (expression1)|yy(expression2)",string) ,you can not combine anything that expression1 is totally different from expression2,how can you write the proper and complete command?`re.search("xx (expression1)|yy(expression2)",string).group(i)` ,in some situation,i is 1,other situation i is 2 ??

Comment: @it_is_a_literature, in Python you can't as far as I know (In Perl there is a special group (?|(..)|(.)) that gives the groups in the alternatives the same numbers). In Python you have to evaluate the resulting `MatchObject` and check in which group your result is.